# Specman: Why test has not finished after the MAIN sequence is finished?

Tags: specman, e, test-bench

a test I've wrote does not finishes after the MAIN sequence is finished.
I did not raise TEST_DONE objection.. and the objections I did raised were all dropped. 
Actually the test finished long after all sequence's flow is done, on TEST BENCH timeout..
Do you have any idea what may prevent a test from ending?
I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: If that's caused by a pending objection you could try "show objections" on the Specman command line.
Is the simulation time still progressing in the end?

Comment: on 2nd thought, the problem may be that you did NOT use TEST_DONE. In that case the test can only be stopped by a stop_run().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I've overridden the `vr_ad_sequence`'s `post_body()` method and it turns out that it drops `TEST_DONE` (Specman UVM vr_ad package). The problem code:

To prevent the test from ending before all MY objections were dropped, the next code was added:

```
extend MAIN vr_ad_sequence {
    post_body()@sys.any is only {
        // Wait till all (my) objections are dropped
        sync true ( my_env.get_objection_counter(MY_OBJECTIONS) == 0 );
    };
};
```

**The solution** was: Change "`is only`" to "`is first`".